# ADF and OnPrem DevOps

Tags: azure-data-factory

Does anyone know if we can use Azure Data Factory with On Prem DevOps instead of the Cloud DevOps? This is a government company and can't store the data in the Cloud, nor code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to let you know that devops is there on azure goverment cloud also :
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azuregov/azure-devops-server-in-azure-government/
Thanks
Himanshu